# run command as root via php

Tags: php, apache, sudo, su

I have a php script which contains su. when I run it in shell it ask for root password and works well. but now I want make an interface for it. as you know all command in php-apache runs as www-data user and this user doesn't have specified password or it's not in sudoers. so I can't use "echo pass | sudo -S ..." because I don't know what is www-data's password and It is not logical on every server set password for www-data or add it in sudoers+nopass, is it?

What solution can you suggest to solve this problem?

one of my commands:

```
su -c \"/usr/sbin/dmidecode -s baseboard-serial-number | tr \  \-\"
```

Comment: Take a look at [suexec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) should be best library choice as it does not requires any additional extensions.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('example.com');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'pass')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('whoami');
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
?>
```

Another alternative is [libssh2](http://pecl.php.net/ssh2), but it has to be compiled separately and is notoriously `difficult` to setup/use.

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell, you can easily get a shell with root. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);

$strCmd = "\"/usr/sbin/dmidecode -s baseboard-serial-number | tr \  \-\"";
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd($strCmd);

echo $return1;// return from your command
```